# Add timeinterval in observable collection using linq

Tags: c#, wpf, linq

I'm Learning Linq by converting the sql queries into linq. I have a table which has time intervals. I want to add the time intervals

Input:

```
Total Time

00:00:14 
00:00:55 
00:00:40
```

output:

```
Total TIme Taken

00:01:49
```

The sql query which i used to convert the above Input to output

```
     SELECT count(*) as total_claimCount, 
     CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),SUM(DATEDIFF(second, '0:00:00', [Total Time])) /3600) + ':' 
     + RIGHT('00'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),(SUM(DATEDIFF(second, '0:00:00', [Total Time])) 
     %3600)/60),2)  + ':' +  RIGHT('00'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),SUM(DATEDIFF(second, 
    '0:00:00', [Total Time]))
     %60),2) AS Total_time_taken  FROM dbo.[opcod Audit Information] 
     where [End Time] is not null
```

Now I want to convert the above query in linq. I have stored the table data into a observable collection called `ModelclassTable`.

Thanks.

Edit : Table data

The data type of all the there columns are varchar.

[image]

Comment: Please show us the actual original data in the table so we can see what your `DATEDIFF` etc are trying to achieve.

Comment: @mjwills updated the question.

Comment: a) Why are you storing times as varchar? b) Your question says 14 seconds, but the image shows 13 seconds. Why the difference?

Comment: 1) I'm inhering a old table where they stored the time interval as varchar. As of now I can't able to do anything with respect to changing the datatype.
2) That is a typo error. I will chage it.

Comment: No I'm not using Entitiy Framework. I Just using Ado.net to pull the data from table and storing it in observable collection for further usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this should suffice.

Given table name *Table*, Column name *TotalTime*:

```
TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(Table.Select(x => TimeSpan.Parse(x.TotalTime).Ticks).Sum());
```

`ts` object will contain the sum of the values.

**Although as a lot of other people pointed out, long term resolution is definitely not storing Time values as varchar.**

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is not very wise to store date/time informations as `varchar`. So you should think about using the `datetime` column type. Also you should maybe use an OR mapper (like EntityFramework) to interact with your database, so that you don't have to hassle with the plumbing details about SQL security, etc.

Nevertheless, given is a list of string pairs, representing the start and date time of an event:

```
public class EventData
{
    public string Start { get; set; }
    public string End { get; set; }

    public TimeSpan CalculateDuration()
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Start)
           || String.IsNullOrEmpty(End))
        {
            // What should happen, if start or end is not set?
        }

        // What should happen, if parsing fails?
        var start = DateTime.Parse(Start);
        var end = DateTime.Parse(End);

        // What should happen, if start is later then end??
        return end - start;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{Start} - {End} => {CalculateDuration()}";
    }
}

private static readonly Random random = new Random();

private static EventData CreateSample()
{
    var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
    var start = now.AddSeconds(random.Next(1000));
    var end = start.AddSeconds(random.Next(1000));

    return new EventData
    {
        Start = start.ToString(),
        End = end.ToString()
    };
}
```

With these helpers we can now quite easily calculate the sums:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var someEvents = Enumerable
        .Range(1, 10)
        .Select(_ => CreateSample())
        .ToList();

    foreach (var item in someEvents)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }

    // Here we calculate the sum, by using .Aggregate()
    var all = someEvents.Aggregate(TimeSpan.Zero, (sum, item) => sum + item.CalculateDuration());
    Console.WriteLine(all);

    Console.WriteLine("Finished");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Last but not least:
This code example is really only an example. There is so much wrong in storing and using values this way (like store dates as string, calculate the duration every time and not only once, no argument checks, no exception handling, etc.). So please continue learning and try to find out what's all wrong in your code and in my example. Hopefully in a few months you'll look at this code and think the same way. Try to find out on how to use something like EF or Dapper and then at the last step you can start thinking about LINQ.